# How to include a html/js project into a vue project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I found this nice and simple code for a tetris game: https://github.com/CodeExplainedRepo/Tetris-JavaScript

I want to simply include it into my vue project. Is this possible or would I have to sort everything into data(), methods etc.?

Comment: Just copy the html (canvas/div) from the github project and use the js file...

Comment: How to exactly use the js files? In index.html? (If so: how exactly, couldnt figure it out yet..)

Comment: Dude... you are coding a vue page and cant include a external js file and 4 lines of html?
He included a youtube in which he explains how he coded the game, watch it.

Comment: I understand what's happening in the code itself, I just don't know how to import the js files into a vue project.

Comment: The same as in the tetris game html code... `<script src="tetris.js"></script>`